# Git bash error: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: git, git-bash, github-for-windows

Whenever I try to execute a command on gitbash I get the error that.

"The system cannot find the path specified."

Be it git pull or git commit, I get the error.

Even if I try using Git GUI or Git from Visual Studio, I get the same error message.

When I try to open the git GUI the same error message pop up opens up and then on click of ok the whole git GUI closes.

[POP up error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLkZY.png)

Apparently, it happens only for one repo. The other repos in my system are working fine.
I tried to clone the repo again to a different folder, but the error message started poping there also.
Others using this repo are not facing any issues.
I have tried restarting and updating the git to the latest, but that also didn't help.

The OS is windows 10.

Comment: hi dinesh, welcome to stackoverflow. may we know what is the command you wanted to execute?

Comment: @BagusTesa Updated the question with the details.

Comment: What it looks like to me is that this repo has a pre-commit message hook, which is a command that gets called just before a commit goes in.  My guess is that repo was designed for an operating system other than the one you're using.

Comment: What OS are you using? If you can list in your question the repo path and any command you use to get this error message, we may be able to help further.

Comment: hi dinesh, first thing to find is at least what those pre-commit hook do. it might call some external toolkit that you dont have. the toolkit might be os-related tools from a different os. it can also be custom stuff the repository owner cooked.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: That smells like a repo with a file that's not valid/supported on Windows. E.g., maybe you have a space at the beginning or end of a file name, or you depend on a symlink, or you have one of a few other file situations that are legal on Linux but not supported by Windows file systems.

Comment: Another idea: your pop-up error (you should really provide that as text, not an image, but anyway) points to the `prepare-commit-msg` hook. Have a look at `.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg` to see if it tries to invoke something not installed on your machine.